# Get corrupted *.zip archives list

Tags: archive, zip

Sorry for my bad English. I have a folder with ***.zip** archives. And this folder contains corrupted archives. How can I get corrupted archives list?

I need to check folder and remove corrupted ***.zip** archives. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just something quick.  You can use the `-T` switch for the `zip` command to test the archive to see if it is good or not.  So, if you run something like `for i in *.zip; do zip -T "$i"; done` from that directory it should be able to show you what zip archives are good and which ones are bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working.

Comment: So, how I can to remove file, if is corrupted? I'm just started to use linux, so I don't know.

Comment: `rm filename` will delete the file.

Comment: You may be able to fix corrupted zip archives with `zip -F ...` or `zip -FF file.zip --out fixed.zip`.

Comment: Extending @Terrance comment ... Something like `for f in *.zip; do if ! zip -Tqq "$f" > /dev/null; then echo rm -v -- "$f"; fi; done`